# Rubymine - how to format the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, rubymine

I'm using JetBrains Rubymine for developing Rails applications. It's a great IDE but unfortunately I didn't find how to format the hTML or Ruby  code.

Any suggestiongs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Ctrl + Alt + I` for Auto-indent line(s)

For [more](https://shortcutworld.com/RubyMine/linux/JetBrains-RubyMine_Shortcuts) keymaps.

Answer (score 12):

In OS X keymap try this one: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This (Cmd+Alt+L) hides/shows line numbers in my RubyMine.

Answer (score 8):

`Code` | `Reformat Code...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Windows default keymap).